# Nuclide Ios Simulator Logs are empty

Tags: react-native, nuclide-editor

I just updated some packages in Atom and now I can't see any logs from iOS simulator :/

Atm I have:
Atom - 1.10.2
Nuclide - 0.171.0

I'm doing:
`Nuclide Ios Simulator Logs: Start`
I got the console with "Showing: 7 Sources", all selected and "iOS Simulator" Process is started, yet console remains empty :/

I've also try doing:
`Nuclide Ios Simulator Logs: Restart`
but also no luck.

Anyone got similar issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/899)

Options:

- **Use ChromeDevTools console** *(On Chrome, Cmd+Alt+J)*
- **Use device system log** *(On device, use Cmd+ / )*

*Note: for Chrome option make sure Debug Remote JS is enabled*

Comment: Damn... Thanks for heads-up. I ended up reverting to previous version.